# how to draw million rectangles with solid color fill using three js?

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

I am using threeJS for my project and the ask is to draw millions of rectangles with a solid fill. I have the coordinates of all those rectangles. The program should be memory efficient and it should not consume GPU to draw a single shape i.e. there should be only a single draw call to draw all those shapes. I tried multiple ways but did not succeed. any help would be really appreciated.

Here is one of the program which i tried

```
    const geometry = new BufferGeometry();
    // Set up the vertex positions as a Float32Array
    const positions = new Float32Array(4 * 3 * this.customShapes.length);
    const indexArray = [];
    let indexCounter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.customShapes.length; i++) {
        let rectShape = this.customShapes[i];
        positions[i * 12 + 0] = rectShape.x1;
        positions[i * 12 + 1] = rectShape.y1;
        positions[i * 12 + 2] = 0;
        positions[i * 12 + 3] = rectShape.x1;
        positions[i * 12 + 4] = rectShape.y2;
        positions[i * 12 + 5] = 0;
        positions[i * 12 + 6] = rectShape.x2;
        positions[i * 12 + 7] = rectShape.y2;
        positions[i * 12 + 8] = 0;
        positions[i * 12 + 9] = rectShape.x2;
        positions[i * 12 + 10] = rectShape.y1;
        positions[i * 12 + 11] = 0;
        indexArray[i * 6 + 0] = indexCounter;
        indexArray[i * 6 + 1] = indexCounter + 1;
        indexArray[i * 6 + 2] = indexCounter + 2;
        indexArray[i * 6 + 3] = indexCounter;
        indexArray[i * 6 + 4] = indexCounter + 2;
        indexArray[i * 6 + 5] = indexCounter + 3;
        indexCounter += 4;
    }
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
    geometry.setIndex(indexArray);

    const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color });

    // Create a mesh and add it to the scene
    const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.name = this.key;
    group.add(mesh);
```

In this program it does not draw one of the rectangle if i use the below coordinates:

```
[
{
    "Coordinates": [
        [
            -0.45,
            0.89
        ],
        [
            -0.45,
            1.0
        ],
        [
            0.48,
            1.0
        ],
        [
            0.48,
            0.89
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "Coordinates": [
        [
            0.6699999999999999,
            2.69
        ],
        [
            0.6699999999999999,
            0.89
        ],
        [
            0.81,
            0.89
        ],
        [
            0.81,
            2.69
        ]
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried using BufferGeometry, InstancedBufferGeometry. Using bufferGeometry, it worked once but later on i found some of the rectangles are missing.

Comment: @callback, i updated my question with the program i am using now.

Comment: `rectShape.x1; rectShape.y1`, what are these fields `x1`, `y1`? You've got no such fields in your example data, there are just arrays of arrays.

Comment: I am creating object using example data in my program. I have not attached complete program.